# How do I initialise QueryDSL SQL template dynamically using datasource

Tags: spring, spring-data, querydsl

I have a datasource object. I need to initialise QueryDSL template based on database type. One way I found is like this,

```
SQLTemplates sqltemplate;
String dbname = dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
if(dbname.equals("PostgresSQL"))
{
 sqltemplate = PostgreSQLTemplates.builder().printSchema().build();
}
else
...
```

Is there any other way to do this? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is about right, but I would abstract it away in a `QueryFactory`. For example look at the `SQLQueryFactory`: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-sql/src/main/java/com/querydsl/sql/SQLQueryFactory.java#L32 . You can extend that to derive the dialect from the datasource. Then at other places instead of having to construct a new query you just inject the `QueryFactory` bean and call `queryFactory.select(...)...`.